# what happens to a "local" var after expression?

Tags: swift, local, var

### Note: "local" meaning contained with in {}

What happens to `localVar` after `func` has been expressed?

```
var constantVarHolder = Int()

func NameOfFunc(){
    var localVar = Int()
    if X = 0 {
        localVar = 3
    }
    else {
        localVar = 4
    }
    constantVarHolder = localVar
}
```

Does it become de-initialized, as in no longer using any memory or CPU?

---

I understand that If I changed the code to..

```
var singleVar = Int()

func NameOfFunc() {
    if X = 0 {
        singleVar = 3
    }
    else {
        singleVar = 4
    }
}
```

..would speed up the timing and memory usage for the duration the expression of `func`.

---

But after `func` has completed, would both codes leave your system in identical states?

Comment: What the..., your swift method has no parameters and has no method name. Please reread how to use methods in swift. And yes, local variables disappear (dealloc) after your program exits the scope of the variable.

Comment: I understand, this is just theoretical code for example purpose. All I'm curious about is what happens to local variables...and you answered, ty

Comment: Yeah, once they're out of scope they immediately get dealloced.

Comment: They're called local variables, and you shouldn't name them such either. Localized and Localization refer to text translation and shouldn't be used here.

Comment: You code isn't real code so your question isn't a meaningful question. Please provide code that actually compiles, and ask a question that has a meaning.

Comment: @matt that's why I commented that this is just theoretical code and my question is simply about local variable de allocation outside of it's scope.

Comment: No, but I mean `func { if ...` isn't even legal Swift syntax. It isn't even theoretical code. It's nonsense. At least supply an example that _compiles_.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your first example doesn't do what you expect it to do (you're shadowing `localVar`). But I assume you really meant this:

```
var constantVarHolder = Int()

func NameOfFunc(){
    var localVar = Int()
    if X = 0 {
       localVar = 3
    }
    else {
        localVar = 4
    }
    constantVarHolder = localVar
}
```

The short answer is that the optimizer is free to rewrite your code in ways that are logically the same, so your assertion that the second version would be faster than the first (as I've given it) is not correct. They could easily be the identical. The compiler is free to assign local variables to registers, so there may be no RAM usage at all. These variable would be stored on the stack in any case, but it really doesn't matter to this case.

Your question about "CPU" doesn't make sense in this context at all. Variables don't use CPU time. Computation does.

"leave your system in identical states" is an over-broad term. Almost certainly the state will be different in some way. But yes, the global variable will have the same value in either case (assuming you write you code as I've provided it), and all the local variables will have been freed (if they ever existed, which is unlikely).

It's really hard to imagine a case where this question is useful. Even if the optimizer doesn't remove the local stack variable, any tiny time difference of moving an immediate value to the stack and then copying from the stack to RAM is dwarfed by the cost of calling the function in the first place (assuming it isn't inlined). If you're seriously trying to speed up this function, you're looking at this in completely the wrong way.

That said, the way to answer your questions is to look at the assembly output. In Xcode, open the Assistant Editor, and select "Assembly" and then select at the bottom "Profile" or "Release" so it's optimized. If you care about this level of optimization, you'll need to get used to reading that output so you can see what code is actually running.

Comment: I have zero prior Computer Science education. This question was to help me wrap my head around the resource usage to allocate a local variable. I am not trying to speed up this particular code, as it is very simple already. I am simply trying to have a better understanding of what is happening to the system so that it will help me write more optimally. "Variables don't use CPU time. Computation does," does it take computation to alloc a New Var? I appreciate your thought out response. It has given me a better grasp on the concept. NOTE: I tried "Assembly" but Assistant Editor is blank.

Comment: Local variables that aren't objects require no allocation. They're stored on the stack and the act of allocating them only requires moving the stack pointer. Generally allocating heap memory (objects for instance) doesn't actually require much CPU work. It mostly is slow because it requires locking the memory pool. There are many optimizations around that (not related to the compiler). Local Swift structs are generally on the stack, so they can be very fast, but they can be moved to the heap if they escape the frame.

Comment: Studying C is very educational for this kind of stuff. Swift, and most modern languages, are very complicated based on decades of learning how to optimize memory. Unoptimized C is much easier to reason about. (Who would think that C would be easier for a beginner?) You may enjoy this C Bootcamp, which dives into these kinds of issues. http://gribblelab.org/CBootcamp/7_Memory_Stack_vs_Heap.html

Comment: (And almost all documents explaining how this or that language or compiler does things assumes you know how C does it.)